# Multiple definitions of main

Tags: c++, lua, definition, program-entry-point

how do I correctly implement Lua in a C++ program? I downloaded the Lua source, put the .c files in my src folder and the .h files in my include folder, included lua.h in my program's source code (with extern "C"{} of course) and hit "Build".

That's how all the tutorials tell me to use Lua with a C++ project.

But now I get the error "multiple definition of main" and some Symbols in the Lua code that could not be resolved. I understand what the first error means (conflict because Lua has a main and my program also has one), but how can I solve it?

Or did I understand something completely wrong about implementing Lua in a C++ program?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check to make sure you didn't include `luac.c`, `lua.c`, and the source for any other programs that are included with Lua in with your source code.  Lua's source includes a few extra utilities (i.e., luac), and chances are you've just included them in the project and forgotten to remove them, thus resulting in having more than one `main`.

In short, those are separate programs that you *don't* add to your project.  If you can, just build Lua normally, link to the library, and include the header files as normal.

So, on the point of you misunderstanding how to use Lua, you probably did to some degree.  It is entirely possible to just copy Lua's source into your code, though probably not advisable.  What you really want to do is pull up the extracted Lua source in a terminal and build it.  Then (according to Lua's `INSTALL` document), you'll want to type `make platform`, where you'll replace `platform` with whichever platform you're currently using (i.e., I'd use `macosx`, you might use `linux`, refer to the `INSTALL` for which platforms are supported).  After that, it's up to you if you want to install it or not, but you'll just do `make install` (or `sudo make install`) to get that done.

After that, either add the appropriate linker flags when compiling to link to Lua (e.g., `-llua`) or alter your project's settings in your editor of choice to do roughly the same thing.  That said, you'll want to refer to the `INSTALL` document provided with Lua for complete instructions on this.

Comment: I'm only including these: lua.h, lualib.h and lauxlib.h. That's what the tutorials told me.

Comment: Yes, but I'm referring to the .c files which, quoting you, you "put ... in [your] src folder."  You need to cut out the unnecessary files or, better yet, remove Lua from your project and just link to the compiled library.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to remove lua.c. Where would I get the libs? On lua.org there's only the source files to download.

Comment: @blubber You have to build the libraries yourself, but it's fairly simple - I included some really basic instructions in my answer, but you can just read the `INSTALL` document provided with Lua for more complete and not overly simplified information.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers. :) But if I have to build Lua myself, e.g. say on Windows, then another dev, e.g. on Linux, would need to build Lua himself to work on my code? And If I just put the Lua source into my project there's no need to buil Lua on every platform. So, what'S the exact reason to use the compiled libs instead of simply putting the source into the project?

Comment: Using the libraries means that if they want to swap out the version you chose for another version, then someone else can easily do so.  As is, they'd have to pull the code out of your project and go through what you went through as well.  Chances are building the libraries is easier for them than sorting through whatever source you bundle with your project.

Comment: @blubberbernd: Not really, your opinion is somewhat wrong. This would be true for unknown libraries, but since Lua is really popular, Linux developer would just type something like 'sudo yast install lua-devel' and that's it, no need to build Lua since it is included in majority of Linux distros.

Comment: @blubberbernd: Same is applicable for Windows, you can use Lua headers and compiler will link your program to dll automatically. As a developer, I would prefer the sources to be as cleaner as possible, without libraries which can be installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm embedding Lua in my projects other way around, preferred way, IMO: [compiled](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLua) Lua as a static library.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the two main() blocks in Lua.c an Luac.c, then hit build and run again.

I made this on Lua 5.3.